# any appindicator replacement in macOS

Tags: macos, gtk, appindicator

the `GtkStatusIcon` in GTK2 is depreacted in GTK3, and most app use `appindicator` to replace the `GtkStatusIcon`. But it sounds that `appindicator` is not available in MacOS, is there any library can work like `GtkStatusIcon` and works in MacOS and Linux? Thanks.